# How to find models in scene without changing origin point?

Tags: texturing, uv, photogrammetry

I have been doing some experiments with photogrammetry and i imported some models into Blender but I realized after I imported them all that I could not find my models.

I rechecked my photogrammetry program and found that I had left the models positioned over in the next county from the origin point before I imported into blender.

I imported into Blender four models that each had between I dunno 1-4 millions verts each.

Anyway I already started rebuilding my photogrammetry models with the same settings from the actual origin point so i'll reimport into blender later.

But if I do this again and my models end up 50 real life miles from the origin (not an exaggeration) how can i zoom to my models in blender without changing their position in relation to their origin point? I can't change their position or scale because i'll be taking the models back into my photogrammetry program later for textures and uvs and etc., And i need all my old depth map and density cloud data to stick perfectly.

Trying to rescale and reorient 3d models after messing up their placement and size is a nightmare FUBAR so I absolutely need their origin to stay the same while i work in Blender.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello :). The origin is only relevant in *Object mode*. You can move/rotate the geometry in *edit mode*, and the origin point will stay where it was.

Comment: Also, you can use *View > Frame selected* to zoom in on the geometry no matter how far from the origin it is.

Answer (score 0):

frame all:home key

view selected:  In the outliner, select the model, and press the period key on your Numpad.

To move the entire model to the world origin:  In the outliner, select the model, press shift+s on your keyboard, and there should be a pie menu that says "selection to cursor".

Your settings may be different, but the actions should be the same.
[image]

Comment: Thank you all very much for the quick replies.